# Better way to convert JSONtoken to Datasource

Tags: json, vb.net, type-conversion, datasource

I have created a webservice with a MySQL database, PHP and JSON to up- and download data. The JSON-container consists of 3 Tokens: 'geslaagd' (as Boolean), 'tekst' (as String) and 'inhoud' (as Array). The JSON will be converted so it fits as a DataSource for a Combobox. It works fine but I have a problem with the way the code looks now.

First it looked like this:

```
Public Function VerkrijgGroepen() As JsonGroepenContainer

    ' Haal de Groepen uit een JSONobject en retouner deze aan aanvrager.
    Dim mJsonGet As String = JsonObjectDownloaden(My.Settings.ODB_UrlWebservice & My.Settings.ODB_BestandGroepenDownloaden)
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JsonGroepenContainer)(mJsonGet)

End function

Public Class JsonObjectGroepenContainer     ' This is the Container-Class for database-table 'Groepen'
    Public Property geslaagd As Boolean
    Public Property tekst As String
    Public Property groepen As List(Of JsonObjectGroepenInhoud)
End Class

Public Class JsonObjectGroepenInhoud        ' This is the Inhoud-Class (Content-Class) for database-table 'Groepen'
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property naam As String
End Class
```

This meant that I had to code a Container-Class and a Inhoud-Class (Content-Class) for every database-table. So I wanted to create a Container-Class that would work for every table and it works:

```
Public Class JsonContainer              ' This is the Container-Class for all tables in the database.
    Public Property geslaagd As Boolean
    Public Property tekst As String
    Public Property inhoud As List(Of JToken)
End Class
```

But now my code looks like this:

```
Public Function VerkrijgObjecten() As List(Of JsonObjectGroepenInhoud)

    ' Verkrijg JSON van webservice.
    Dim mJson As String = JsonObjectDownloaden(My.Settings.ODB_UrlWebservice & My.Settings.ODB_BestandGroepenDownloaden)
    Dim mJsonParse As JObject = JObject.Parse(mJson)
    Dim geslaagd As Boolean = CBool(mJsonParse("geslaagd"))
    Dim tekst As String = CStr(mJsonParse("tekst"))
    Dim inhoud As JToken = mJsonParse("inhoud")
    Dim groepen As New List(Of JsonObjectGroepenInhoud)

    ' Controleer of verkrijgen van JSON in webservice geslaagd is.
    If geslaagd Then

        ' Zet de inhoud van JSONtoken ("inhoud") om in een lijst met groepen.
        For Each i As JToken In inhoud
            Dim groep As JsonObjectGroepenInhoud = New JsonObjectGroepenInhoud
            groep.id = CInt(i("id"))
            groep.naam = CStr(i("naam"))
            groepen.Add(groep)
        Next
    Else

        ' Stel gebruiker op de hoogte van fout.
        MessageBox.Show(
                "Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het ophalen van de gegevens van de Groepen. De webservice geeft een foutmelding door." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & tekst,
                "Fout in webservice",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error
            )
    End If

    Return groepen

End Function
```

It works fine and the Error handling is better now (more logic) but it looks terrible! And when code looks terrible it usually is terrible!? I have the feeling that this code could be simplified but after 2 days of trying I give up. Is there someone who can help me out? Is there another way or is this it?

Comment: So really you're looking for a way to use the first structure in a general sense so that two different JSONs of `{tekstA: "a", groepenA: { idA: 1, naamA: "n" }}` and `{tekstB: "b", groepenB: { id: 2, naamB: "o" }}` can be parsed to same object on c# side? What do all these different JSONs look like anyway? Can you get the server to shape them the same if they are to be treated the same? How about transforming the Json before it is parsed if you don't want to write a custom parser that can understand all different shapes?

Comment: Thank you Caius for your quick respons. I've changed a few things already and now I'm satisfied. In a nutshell: I moved the section where I Dimmed all the variables to another section in the code. Kind of a customized parser, just like you suggested.